# Additional zeros in output

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image: screenshot]

I have a problem with the output of my program showing additional two zeros when I'm clicking the content to show the output. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
$(MyOrder).each(function () {
    var markup = '<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="ViewDetails(\'' + $(this).find("OrderNo").text() + '\',\'' + $(this).find("OrderStatus").text() + '\',\'' + $(this).find("Description").text() + '\',\'' + $(this).find("Filenames").text() + '\')">';
    markup = markup + "<td><label style='textalign:center;'>" + row + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idRefNum"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("OrderNo").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idOrderDate"+row+"' >" + formatDateMMDDYYYY($(this).find("OrderDate").text()) + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idPRNo"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("PRno").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idPRDate"+row+"' >" + formatDateMMDDYYYY($(this).find("PRDate").text()) + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idPONo"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("PoNo").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idPODate"+row+"' >" + formatDateMMDDYYYY($(this).find("PODate").text()) + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idGRDate"+row+"' >" + formatDateMMDDYYYY($(this).find("GRdate").text()) + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td hidden style='text-align:center;'><label style='' id='idIRDate"+row+"' >" + formatDateMMDDYYYY($(this).find("IRDate").text()) + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td style='text-align:left;'><label style='' id='idReqBy"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("RequestedBy").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td style='text-align:right;'><label style='' id='idTotal"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("Total").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "<td style='text-align:left;'><label style='' id='idDesc"+row+"' >" + $(this).find("Description").text() + "</label></td>";
    markup = markup + "</tr>";
    $("#tblMyorder tbody").append(markup);
    var Total = $("#idTotal" + row).text();
    Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
    Total = Total.toLocaleString('en');

    $("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total)); 
    row = row + 1;
});
```

UPDATE: And the definition of `numberWithCommas` is:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

Comment: if you don't want then remove `.toFixed(2)` from your code. here's what it does [Number​.prototype​.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Well, it should be only two zeros not 4

Comment: Please show an example of what you are getting and what you are wanting. Then using a debugger step through the code and see at what point its being formatted incorrectly i.e. `Total.toLocaleString('en')` may apply formatting, as may `numberWithCommas`. If it turns out to be `numberWithCommas` then post the code for that. Your logic it a bit odd, because you are converting the number to a string in 3 places, `.toFixed(2)`, `Total.toLocaleString('en')` (unsure whether this will work since its now a string not a number), and then `numberWithCommas`. Maybe format once only?

Comment: Hi, here's my code: $("#tblMyorder tbody").append(markup);
                                    var Total = $("#idTotal" + row).text();
                                    Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
                                    Total = Total.toLocaleString('en');
                                    $("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total));

Comment: numberwithcommas won't work with my program

Comment: Dale, the function of the code was posted above this thread

Comment: I'm just a newbie in javascript that's why i'm asking for any fix suggestions/solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code which I will document below. One thing you have to understand about JavaScript is that it is loosely typed and it doesn't check whether you are passing the correct type to a function.

Your full (relevant) code is:

```
var Total = $("#idTotal" + row).text();
Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
Total = Total.toLocaleString('en');
$("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total));
```

So line by line: This line gets some text, which is mean to represent a number. So `Total` is a string here.

```
var Total = $("#idTotal" + row).text(); // Example '1234.4567987'
```

This line both attempts to convert `Total` (a string) to a float, and then formats it to 2 decimal places. So far so good, `Total` is still a string.

```
Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2); // Example '1234.45'
```

This line also attempts to convert a number to a string **but** at this point `Total` is already a formatted string. So it just returns it as it is (does nothing).

```
Total = Total.toLocaleString('en'); // Example still '1234.45'
```

If however you did the following you would get something much closer to what you are looking for.

```
parseFloat($("#idTotal" + row).text()).toLocaleString('en'); // 1,234.456
```

But instead you call this line which one assumes is attempting to add a thousands comma to a number. Also it probably is expecting a number, whereas you are passing in a string.

```
$("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total));
```

So in summary, you are attempting to format your number (`Total`) into a string 3 different times, but only the first attempt is working because after that you are passing a string instead of a number.

And it would appear that the function `numberWithCommas` is adding more decimal points than you desire.

To assist further we need to see the definition of the function `numberWithCommas` but as a start you could try:

```
$("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(parseFloat($("#idTotal" + row).text())));
```

---

UPDATE

The function `numberWithCommas` happily accepts either a number or a string which is good. However when testing your exact code using the test string "1234.4567987" I get out "1234.45" exactly as expected. In fact the `toLocaleString` is not required as it doesn't do anything to a string. So the following code is working as expected:

```
var Total = '1234.4567987';
Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
alert(numberWithCommas(Total)); // 1,234.45
```

as does

```
var Total = '15000.0000';
Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
alert(numberWithCommas(Total)); // 15,000.00
```

I was unable to break this code. Therefore the core of what you are trying to do is working.

Please modify your code as follows and then run it and report back what appears in your console:

```
var Total = $("#idTotal" + row).text();
console.log('1: '+Total);
Total = parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2);
console.log('2: '+Total);
console.log('3: '+numberWithCommas(Total));
$("#idTotal"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total));
```

Comment: Hi Dale, Heres the code of number with commas:                                                                                                                function numberWithCommas(x) {
            var parts = x.toString().split(".");
            parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            return parts.join(".");
        }

Comment: @JerzonBarbacena well that code works as expected. Try removing the line with `toLocaleString` and see if that helps.

Comment: And if that doesn't work please see the last part of my answer for a final suggestion.

Comment: Hi Dale, the statement $("Total"+ row).text(numberWithCommas(Total)); in your latest update stops my system from loading the data. when i removed this line, it worked but i wasn't get the expected output.

Comment: Given its identical to your original code (I only added the `console.log` statements), thats not possible. I think you are going to have to take some training on JavaScript and JavaScript debugging, because I can't debug your system any further - all the code I have shown above works [here](https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html)

Comment: Did you try just removing `toLocaleString ` before copying the code with the `console.log` statements?

Comment: @JerzonBarbacena Also what is the output from the 3 `console.log()` lines?

Comment: here's the output 1: 15000.00
2: 15000.00
3: 15,000.00

Comment: The final result (#3) seems to be exactly what you are trying to accomplish?